# How can you clear a Matplotlib text box that was previously drawn?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can make text boxes in `matplotlib` fine. But I dont see how to remove them from a rendered plot?  There seems to be no `figure.text.clear()` or `figure.text(visible=False)` after you draw a text box?  How is this done?  and unlike legends, you seem to be unable to make them draggable?

Comment: `figure.text.remove()`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Text boxes are artists.  As such, you should be able to do lots of things with them **if you keep a reference to them**.  Hence, in any plotting code, instead of

```
fig.text(0, 0, 'My text')
```

you can do

```
textvar = fig.text(0, 0, 'My text')
```

If you've lost the references, though, all the text objects can be found in the `texts` attribute:

```
fig.texts # is a list of Text objects
```

In version 1.3.1, doing `textvar.remove()` generates a NotImplementedError (apparently fixed in 1.4).  However, you can get around that to some degree by setting the visibility to False.

```
for txt in fig.texts:
    txt.set_visible(False)
```

will make all your text boxes disappear.

Comment: @tcaswell I didn't think to check the most recent version, that is with 1.3.1. Awesome that it's fixed in 1.4!

Comment: I have tired the above method of text.set_visible(False), but the text just gets overridden each time i update the text value.

Comment: If you are going to be updating the figure text you might want to consider setting the  text to an empty string:"" e.g. fig.set_texts(""). It would delete the current text without removing the variable. Something useful when doing animations.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use `fig.texts` or `ax.texts` to print the list of all the titles present in that `fig/axes`.
2. Use `del` keyword of python to delete that specific `text`.

**Consider the following example:**

```
print(fig.texts)
```

Ouput:

```
[Text(-0.3, 5, 'Features data distribution'),
 Text(-0.3, 4.5, 'Secondary title')]
```

Say you have to delete 'Secondary title'

```
del fig.texts[1]
print(fig.texts)
```

Output:

```
[Text(-0.3, 5, 'Features data distribution')]
```

**In the figure that title would be deleted.**

Comment: From Matplotlib 3.7 on, `fig.texts` and `ax.texts` have been made immutable : https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html

How can we delete `text` from these tuples now ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to remove `text()` by using `Artist.remove()` and it works fine.
We can also show/hide artist by using `Artist.set_visible()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.artist import Artist

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

frame = plt.text(0.6, 0.7, "hello world!", size=50,
                 ha="center", va="center",
                 )

# To hide the artist
Artist.set_visible(frame, False)
# To show the artist
Artist.set_visible(frame, True)
# To remove the artist
Artist.remove(frame)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to do this with matplotlib.figure.Figure:

```
# gca = get current axis
del fig.gca().texts[0]
# Redraw
fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```